# Add a random number to an existing number to produce output in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, input

I am trying to add a random number to an existing number. I am able to get the output in Unity console, but in the inspector, I can see that the public variable is on a non stop loop.

[image: This is my inspector view, with the final result selected.]

I intend to produce the result when I press the enter key. Is this an efficient way, or can I improve on the code? I am a beginner, and passionate to learn.

Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LearningScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int number1 = 5;
    public int number2 = 10;
    public int number3=20;
    public int finalResult;
    public string statement = "NO KEY PRESSED";

    void Update()
    {
        input ();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return))
            Debug.Log (finalResult);
    }

    void Start(){}

    int addnumbers(int num1,int num2)
    {
        int additionResult = num1 + num2;
        return additionResult;
    }

    void input()
    {
        int randomNumber = Random.Range (1, 10);
        finalResult=    addnumbers (number1, randomNumber); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, your problem is in calling `input()` on each `Update()`. You would replace your `Update` function as follows (be particularly mindful of the closing brackets on the `if` statement):

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return)) {
        input ();
        Debug.Log (finalResult);
    }
}
```

Given the context of the question, lets have a closer look at *why* this is the problem.

#### The Update Method

The `Update()` method comes from `MonoBehaviour`. You will notice that at the top, your class is called `LearningScript : MonoBehaviour`. The `: MonoBehaviour` offers extension of the original `MonoBehaviour` class that provides most of the functionality, in Unity.

`Update()` is a re-iterating method that will call *on each game update*. You should use this as your main starting point for logic that repeats itself, but use caution: Updating too much can easily lead to freezing. In this case, you are actually not doing anything to freeze your game. You are simply refreshing `finalResult` so quickly that it overrides any real-time changes you may make, often quicker than you would notice.

By ensuring you only update your input *when you need to*, i.e. when the user first presses the Enter button, you ensure that your code is far more efficient.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return)) {
        input ();
        Debug.Log (finalResult);
    }
}
```

#### Notes on `MonoBehaviour` methods

`Update` is but one of many methods you can implement from the original `MonoBehaviour` class. While it is easily the most common, you will quickly find yourself using other methods, such as `Start`, `FixedUpdate` and `OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)`. You can find a good list, linking you to instructions on each method, under "Messages" in [the Unity API listing for `MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

`Start` is as commonly used as `Update`, as it provides the entry point for code to set up your class. As a result, it is also provided by default, when you create a new script. In your above code, you set everything up when you declare the variables, and could completely remove the `Start() {..}` function without any change to your script.

#### Notes on `if` statements

In your original statement, you write it as follows:

```
if(input)
    doSomething;
```

This is not the wrong way to do it; in fact, it is often a matter of opinion. You will notice that my solution writes it as follows:

```
if(input) {
    doSomething;
    doSomethingElse;
}
```

This part is important: With the use of *multiple* lines, you *must* use enclosing "squiggly brackets" (`{ }`). If you do not, it can cause errors. What is worst; it can cause errors *later* in your class, as your compiler may interpret the statement entirely different to how you intend, and only realise there is a problem when later lines of code do not make sense given its misunderstanding. Long story short, if you have this problem, Unity could very well tell you it is a *completely different* problem, on a *completely different* line. It is important to know that these things do happen, and can lead to some very frustrating moments. Think of it as character building - even the best of us have those stories where we banged our head against a brick wall for hours only to have someone point out the obvious problem after a minute of review.

#### Notes on naming conventions

Naming conventions are even more debatable, when it comes down to the semantics of how we should name things. One major thing I will point out is the use of capital letters to start each new word in a name. You seem to be following this standard, except for your classes. While you surely would have no problem interpretting `addnumbers`, most would tell you it should be `addNumbers`.

A personal preference of mine is to start with a lower case, if I am naming a variable, or upper case, if I am naming a method. So I would use `AddNumbers`. This just makes it easier to quickly identify the variables and the methods.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you call `input()` in the Update method, which is called each frame. Put your `input()` in the input-taking `if` block.

```
void Update()
{  
     if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return))
     {
        input ();
        Debug.Log (finalResult);
     }   
}
```

Now input only gets called once you press down Return.